# process for Importing excel.xslx into Azure Data Studio

Tags: sql-server, macos, ms-access

I'm about to be switched over to an M1 MacBook Pro. I need some insight from current M1 MacBook Pro users.

My current process is

- get data in *.xslx,*.csv from source
- clean up data in the spreadsheet
- import data into MS Access as tables and correct any incorrect data types etc
- export from MS Access OBDC into SQL Server Management Studio

What application should I be using as alternatives? I found Azure Data Studio as a good alternative to SQL Server Management Studio.

What should I be using as my MS Access alternative?

What is your process if you do something similar to mine?

Comment: Why do you even need MS Access in this process? Can't you import directly from excel into SQL Server? A better approach may be to clean up in Excel, then save as text (tab delimited) then import that via Azure Data Studio.

Comment: I'll prob do that, I just used access in the old process as I found it easier to clean the data and set the data types and as there is no version of access for mac, ill do it that way

Comment: Depending on how inconsistent the data is, you might find you can write a stored proc to clean it up inside SQL. . Depends how much manual intervention is required and how dirty the data is